# Getting syntax error when adding a function in awk

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

```
#!/bin/gawk
function convertToCamelCase(text)
{
        split(text, words, " "); for (i=1; i<=length(words); i++) { res = res toupper(substr(words[i],1,1))tolower(substr(words[i],2))" ";
        return res;
}
function convertToThreeDigitDecimal(num)
{
        return sprintf("%7.3f",(num/1000000));
}
BEGIN {
....
```

I am trying to add a function in awk, it is giving me syntax error.

```
bash-3.2$ ./execute_all_stats.sh.bak file.csv
awk: get_mkt_stats.awk.bak:7: function convertToThreeDigitDecimal(num)
awk: get_mkt_stats.awk.bak:7: ^ syntax error
awk: get_mkt_stats.awk.bak:11: BEGIN {
awk: get_mkt_stats.awk.bak:11: ^ syntax error
```

The awk version is:

```
bash-3.2$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
```

I am calling the awk like the following:

```
gawk -F',' -f script.awk ${file}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a closing '}' on your for loop.

```
function convertToCamelCase(text)
{
    split(text, words, " ");
    for (i=1; i<=length(words); i++) { 
        res = res toupper(substr(words[i],1,1)) tolower(substr(words[i],2))" "
     }
 return res;
}
```

I've also added a space in front of `tolower`, just to make that function explicit.